How to Stack a Scatter Plot and a Bar Chart with Discrete and Continuous Y-Axes?
I have created two plots:
The first one is a scatter plot where the x-axis represents time and the y-axis contains discrete values like the names 'Tom' and 'Jerry'.
The second one is a bar chart where the x-axis is also time and the y-axis shows continuous values like height.
I'm now trying to stack these two plots onto the same graph, but I'm not sure how to do it.
Here is the code I have used for each plot:
For the scatter plot:
data.scatter <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), y = c("Tom", "Jerry", "Tom", "Jerry", "Tom"))
ggplot(data.scatter, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()

the scatter plot
For the bar chart:
data.bar <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), y = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50))
ggplot(data.bar, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")


The following is my attempt, but this code is very cumbersome. Is there a simpler way to achieve this effect?
library(tidyverse)

data.scatter <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), y = c("Tom", "Jerry", "Tom", "Jerry", "Tom"))
p1 <- ggplot(data.scatter, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
p1_data <- ggplot_build(p1)$data[[1]]

data.bar <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), y = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50))
p2 <- ggplot(data.bar, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")


p2_data <- ggplot_build(p2)$data[[1]]

p3 <- p2_data %>% ggplot() +
  geom_rect(aes(ymin=ymin,ymax = ymax,xmin = xmin,xmax = xmax)) + 
  geom_text(aes(x=xmin+.45,y=ymax+1,label=ymax)) +
  geom_point(data = p1_data, aes(x = x, y = y*20),inherit.aes = F) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(20,40),labels = c("Tom","Jerry")) + 
  labs(x=NULL,y=NULL)


p3



You could set the limits for the y-axes in both plots to ensure that the axes align when combining them using align_plots from the cowplot package.
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

p1 <- ggplot(data.bar, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(position = "right") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0.5,5.5))  +
  theme_minimal_hgrid()

p2 <- ggplot(data.scatter, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() + labs(x="x")  +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0.5,5.5)) +
  theme_cowplot()

aligned_plots <- align_plots(p1, p2, align="hv", axis="tblr")
ggdraw(aligned_plots[[1]]) + draw_plot(aligned_plots[[2]])




Thank you for your reply. But I hope to stack the two plots instead of vertically concatenating them.

See my edited answer.

The code simplifies the plotting but complicates the data prep. And it uses an auxiliary function and an extra variable fac. The discrete axis is plotted as if it were continuous and the continuous (bars) values are scaled to the "tom" and "jerry" range.
library(ggplot2)

data.scatter <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), y = c("Tom", "Jerry", "Tom", "Jerry", "Tom"))
data.bar <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), y = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50))

data.all <- merge(data.scatter, data.bar, by = "x", suffixes = c(".scatter", ".bar"))

# auxiliary function, makes the code below simpler
chr2int <- function(x, ...) as.integer(factor(x, ...))
# scale the bars ...
(fac <- with(data.all, range(chr2int(y.scatter))/range(y.bar)))
#> [1] 0.10 0.04
# ... to a bit above "jerry"
(fac <- min(fac) * 1.1)
#> [1] 0.044

ggplot(data.all, aes(x, y = y.bar * fac)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = y.bar), vjust = -0.5) +
  geom_point(aes(y = chr2int(y.scatter)), color = "red", size = 3L) +
  xlab("") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "",
    breaks = chr2int(data.all$y.scatter) |> unique(),
    labels = levels(factor(data.all$y.scatter))
  )


Created on 2024-07-24 with reprex v2.1.0
